# how to change this code to be able to solve this challenge?

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm new in programming and I'm trying to solve some problems from online websites. And one of this problems stopped me.
You can download problem here : https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/101/10191.pdf

I don't know how to change this code in order to determine itself where to end reading data from console.

here is the code that I wrote :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE 256

int second_time(char a[])
{
    int hour1, minute1, time;

    hour1 = a[6] - '0';
    hour1 *= 10;
    hour1 += a[7] - '0';

    minute1 = a[9] - '0';
    minute1 *= 10;
    minute1 += a[10] - '0';

    time = (60*hour1) + minute1;
    return time;
}

int first_time(char b[])
{
    int hour2, minute2, time;

    hour2 = b[0] - '0';
    hour2 *= 10;
    hour2 += b[1] - '0';

    minute2 = b[3] - '0';
    minute2 *= 10;
    minute2 += b[4] - '0';

    time = (60*hour2) + minute2;
    return time;
}


int main(void) {
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    int i, j, s, k;
    int first, second, delta;

    scanf("%i", &s);
    getchar();  

    int max[4], max_hour[4];
    int flag = 1;
    for(k=0; k<4; k++)
    {
        max[k] = 0;
    }
    while(flag)
    {
        for(i=0;i<s-1; i++)
        {
            if(i%2 == 0)
            {
                scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", line);

                second = second_time(line); 
                if(s%2 == 0)
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", line);

            first = first_time(line);

            delta = first - second;
            if (delta > max[k])
                max_hour[k] = second;
                max[k] = delta;
            second = second_time(line);
        }       
    }

    for(k=0; k<4; k++)
    {
        if(delta < 60)
            printf("Day #%i: the longest nap starts at %.2i:%.2i and will last for %i minutes.\n", k+1, max_hour[k]/60, max_hour[k]%60, max[k]);    
        else
            printf("Day #%i: the longest nap starts at %.2i:%.2i and will last for %i hours and %i minutes.\n", k+1, max_hour[k]/60, max_hour[k]%60, max[k]/60, max[k]%60); 
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why did you add infinite-loop tag?

Comment: @coderredoc because we don't have any information about length of loop until user enters '\n' character.

Comment: But it will end some day right? How come is it infinite?

Comment: @coderredoc Ok, removed.

Comment: .: you understood?

Comment: `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", line);` is worse than the now obsolete `gets()`.  Use `fgets()` to read user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got AC with the following code

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int s, c, day = 0, z, cp, cb, m;
    int f[480], beg, max;
    int h1, m1, h2, m2;
    int p1, p2;
    char line[256];

    while (scanf("%d\n", &s) != EOF) {
    ++day;

    for (z = 0; z < 480; ++z) f[z] = 1;
    beg = 0;
    max = 0;

    for (c = 0; c < s; ++c) {
        scanf("%d:%d %d:%d", &h1, &m1, &h2, &m2);
        fgets(line, 256, stdin);

        p1 = (h1 - 10) * 60 + m1;
        p2 = (h2 - 10) * 60 + m2;
        for (cp = p1; cp < p2; ++cp) f[cp] = 0;
    }

    c = 0;
    while (c < 480) {
        if (f[c]) {
        cb = c;
        m = 0;
        while (f[c] && c < 480) {
            ++c;
            ++m;
        }
        if (m > max) {
            beg = cb;
            max = m;
        }
        } else {
        ++c;
        }
    }

    printf("Day #%d: the longest nap starts at %02d:%02d and will last for ", day, 10 + beg / 60, beg % 60);
    if (max > 59) printf("%d hours and ", max / 60);
    printf("%d minutes.\n", max % 60);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function scanf() returns the number of items successfully matched. Use this return value in order to set your infinite loop and check whether you've reached EOF. Moreover, for these problems, you should usually print the results instance by instance, you do not need to keep all the answers in a vector (you don't know how large it will be anyway).

Comment: Please illustrate your thoughts with codes, As I said I'm new in programming.

Answer (score 0):

You have assumed the schedules are given in sorted order. It is not. So you need to sort it and then just linearly check the maximum free gap.

*When to stop reading data?*

Just takes input like this

```
    while(scanf("%d",&s)!=EOF) 
    {
        read s schedule.
        sort
        get maximum free gap
        ****BINGO****
        ....
    }

Note: sorting is not relevant to looping but to your AC solution it is.
```

### Code

```
struct schedule
{
   int start;
   int end;
}
struct schedule ss[MAX+1];
while(scanf("%d",&s)!=EOF)----> This is when you know you have to stop when it return EOF
    {
        First element of ss I would set as ss[0]={6000,6000}
        last element of ss  I would set as ss[s]={1080,1080}
        Get s schedules and put them in ss
        sort them
        for each of the elements starting from 1 to s
            get max ( ss[i].start - ss[i-1].end) 
                and corresponding end time.

        get maximum free gap
        ****BINGO****
        ....
    }
```

### As you insisted your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE 256

int second_time(char a[])
{
    int hour1, minute1, time;

    hour1 = a[6] - '0';
    hour1 *= 10;
    hour1 += a[7] - '0';

    minute1 = a[9] - '0';
    minute1 *= 10;
    minute1 += a[10] - '0';

    time = (60*hour1) + minute1;
    return time;
}

int first_time(char b[])
{
    int hour2, minute2, time;

    hour2 = b[0] - '0';
    hour2 *= 10;
    hour2 += b[1] - '0';

    minute2 = b[3] - '0';
    minute2 *= 10;
    minute2 += b[4] - '0';

    time = (60*hour2) + minute2;
    return time;
}


int main(void) {
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    int i, j, s, k;
    int first, second, delta;



    int max[200], max_hour[200];
    int flag = 1;
    for(k=0; k<200; k++)
    {
        max[k] = 0;
    }
    while(scanf("%i", &s)!=EOF)
    {
        getchar();
        for(i=0;i<s-1; i++)
        {
            if(i%2 == 0)
            {
                scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", line);

                second = second_time(line); 
                if(s%2 == 0)
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", line);

            first = first_time(line);

            delta = first - second;
            if (delta > max[k])
                max_hour[k] = second;
                max[k] = delta;
            second = second_time(line);
        }       


        for(k=0; k<s; k++)
        {
            if(delta < 60)
                printf("Day #%i: the longest nap starts at %.2i:%.2i and will last for %i minutes.\n", k+1, max_hour[k]/60, max_hour[k]%60, max[k]);    
            else
                printf("Day #%i: the longest nap starts at %.2i:%.2i and will last for %i hours and %i minutes.\n", k+1, max_hour[k]/60, max_hour[k]%60, max[k]/60, max[k]%60); 
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

### Correct solution

```
typedef struct {
    int st, ed;
} schedule;
int cmp(const void *i, const void *j) {
    schedule *a, *b;
    a = (schedule *)i, b = (schedule *)j;
    return a->st <= b->st;
}
int main() {
    int n, i, a, b, c, d, day = 0;
    schedule TT[100];
    while(scanf("%d", &n) !=EOF) {
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%d:%d %d:%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
            getchar();
            TT[i].st = a*60 + b;
            TT[i].ed = c*60 + d;

        }
        qsort(TT, n, sizeof(schedule), cmp);
        int beg = 600, ans = 0, point;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(( TT[i].st-beg ) > ans)
                ans = (TT[i].st-beg ), point = beg;
            beg = TT[i].ed;
        }
        if((1080 - beg) > ans)
            ans = (1080- beg), point = beg;
        printf("Day #%d: the longest nap starts at ", ++day);
        printf("%02d:%02d and will last for ", point/60, point%60);
        if(ans >= 60)
            printf("%d hours and ", ans/60);
        printf("%d minutes.\n", ans%60);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please illustrate your thoughts with codes, As I said I'm new in programming.

Comment: I think sorting them is not relevant to the length of loop ! let's assume that it is sorted.

Comment: also you can check your code with input given in the PDF document. I did it and it was not working.

Comment: Just try to read it once ..try to implement it says everything

Comment: You did not understood the problem at all.

Comment: what you mean? clarify

Comment: Paste whole code here if you think what you say is correct.

Comment: please use // or /* for commenting !

Comment: Ok let me clarify, Please edit my code and paste the right code here. because I cannot really understand what you mean, but I will understand the soure code surely.

Comment: I submitted your code to that online site, and it was wrong.

Comment: It just resolved the input issue....to get a correct soluton..you need to follow my pseudocode. which i willl write when I get time

Comment: @Uncle.: check it

Comment: it cannot be compiled !

Comment: atleast add those 2 headers...and check small errors

Comment: (scanf("%d", &n) =!=EOF) is it correct ? do you even compile the code you write ?

Comment: check...I am in hurry so I cant do more @Uncle

Comment: so don't answer at all. you waste my time in this way :(

Comment: This is not how you treat people that helped you, @Uncle.